# css position setup

Tags: css

Im trying to setup a centrally aligned div, both vertically and horizontally, im trying to do it by setting the width and height of the div, and then positioning it fixed center and offsetting the margins by 50%.

This is the css im using

```
#404-wrapper    {width:400px; height:200px; position:fixed; left:50%; top:50%; margin-top:-100px; margin-left:-200px;}
#404-wrapper a  {font-size:14px; line-height:120%;}
```

ive also made a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/wnGL3/

but i cant see why it isnt working, any ideas  ?

Comment: IDs can't start with a number I don't think. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rename your markup and css without the number in the front

```
#wrapper    {width:400px; height:200px; position:fixed; left:50%; top:50%; margin-      top:-100px; margin-left:-200px;}
#wrapper a  {font-size:14px; line-height:120%;}
```

Comment: ahh i never knew that so you cant have numbers in a css class/id name or is it just numbers infront ?

Comment: thanks, i would have played around with that all day, and still never got it !

Answer (score 2):

`id` attributes *can* legally start with a number in HTML5, but you'll still have a problem with it in CSS.

If you can't change the id, you can use an **attribute selector**:

```
[id="404-wrapper"] {}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wnGL3/10/

Just for fun, there's another way to do it using unicode escape codes:

```
#\00003404-wrapper {}
```

`\000034` represents the number 4. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wnGL3/11/

Answer (score 1):

ID's cannot start with numbers unfortunately.

From the W3C spec on Id's

> id = name [CS]
>   This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name In this article it described what the 'name' for the ID can be.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens (“-”), underscores (“_”), colons (“:”), and periods (“.”).

Change the ID to wrapper-404 and it works.

```
#wrapper-404    {width:400px; height:200px; position:fixed; left:50%; top:50%; margin-top:-100px; margin-left:-200px;}

#wrapper-404 a    {font-size:14px; line-height:120%;}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/wnGL3/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use position as relative instead of fixed. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

ID's Cannot start with a number in css.

But you can fix it with change

```
#404-wrapper
```

to

```
[id='404-wrapper']
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wnGL3/8/) is an working example.